# Order of the quotient group $\;\mathbb R^*/G^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\mathbb R^*$ be the group of all non zero real number under multiplication and $\,G^*$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb R^*$ consisting of all squares of reals.

What is the order of the quotient group $\;\dfrac{\mathbb R^*}{G^*}$?

Comment: Square *what*? Like, any number that can be written as a square of a real number? That seems like a fancy way of saying "positive reals". Maybe squares of rational numbers?

Comment: $G^*={{x^2/x  in  R^*}}$ @rschwieb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $\;G^* = \{g: g = x^2\mid x \in \mathbb R^*\}$

For each $g\in G^*$, there are *two* $x_i \in \mathbb R^*$ that solve $g = x_i^2,\;$ *exactly one* of which is also in $G^*$.

How does this relate to the number of cosets of $\,G^* \in \mathbb R^*$, recalling that the cosets of $\,G^* \leq \mathbb R^*\,$ necessarily partition $\,\mathbb R^*\,?\;$ Then recall $$\large\left[\mathbb R^*: \,G^*\right] = \left| \frac{\mathbb R^*}{G^*}\right|$$

Comment: user59489: Does this help clear things up?

Comment: two cosets right? so G* is a normal subgroup right?

Comment: Yes, indeed, and you're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: What numbers are *not* squares in $\mathbb{R}^\ast$? Show that if $x\in\mathbb{R}^\ast$, then either $x$ or $-x$ is a square.

Answer (score 5):

Consider $\phi: \mathbb{R}^\ast \to \mathbb{R}^\ast$ given by $\phi(x)=x/|x|$. Then $\phi$ is a homomorphism.
We have $\ker \phi=G^\ast$ because a real number is a square iff it is positive. We also have $\text{im}\, \phi=\{-1,1\}$, which means $G^\ast$ has index 2.

Comment: +1, definitely the proof I prefer, as the quotient group in the question suggests the use of the first isomorphism theorem.